# Identify lego Set that includes a caravan

Tags: set-identification

I have this set that was given to me, but I cannot locate a caravan like this anywhere.  Is this part of a set or something someone just build?  As you can see there are a lot of missing pieces.  Does it ring a bell to anyone?

Thanks a lot

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a small build, slightly altered, from [set 4997 Transport Ferry](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4997-1) from 2008.

[image]

Comment: The web got tired of me looking for the answer for the past month.  Truly amazing you had the answer.  I appreciate your help.  Thanks again